# A fatal error occurs when I upload a sketch from arduino IDE to ESP32-WROOM-32D that has an I2C LCD connected to it

Tags: esp32, fatal-error, i2c, lcd

I am getting a fatal error whenever I try to upload the sketch on scanning for the I2C LCD address.

```
Sketch uses 273449 bytes (20%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 22688 bytes (6%) of dynamic memory, leaving 304992 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
esptool.py v4.5.1
Serial port COM9
Connecting...............
Chip is ESP32-D0WD-V3 (revision v3.1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: a0:b7:65:f5:1d:e0
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 921600
Changed.
WARNING: Failed to communicate with the flash chip, read/write operations will fail. Try checking the chip connections or removing any other hardware connected to IOs.
Configuring flash size...
Flash will be erased from 0x00001000 to 0x00005fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00008000 to 0x00008fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x0000e000 to 0x0000ffff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00010000 to 0x00052fff...
Compressed 17520 bytes to 12170...

A fatal error occurred: Packet content transfer stopped (received 8 bytes)
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2
```

here is the sketch that I was using, it came from https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-i2c-communication-arduino-ide/:

```
/*********
  Rui Santos
  Complete project details at https://randomnerdtutorials.com  
*********/

#include <Wire.h>
 
void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("\nI2C Scanner");
}
 
void loop() {
  byte error, address;
  int nDevices;
  Serial.println("Scanning...");
  nDevices = 0;
  for(address = 1; address < 127; address++ ) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    error = Wire.endTransmission();
    if (error == 0) {
      Serial.print("I2C device found at address 0x");
      if (address<16) {
        Serial.print("0");
      }
      Serial.println(address,HEX);
      nDevices++;
    }
    else if (error==4) {
      Serial.print("Unknow error at address 0x");
      if (address<16) {
        Serial.print("0");
      }
      Serial.println(address,HEX);
    }    
  }
  if (nDevices == 0) {
    Serial.println("No I2C devices found\n");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("done\n");
  }
  delay(5000);          
}
```

and here is the output on the serial monitor whenever I press the "EN" button on the esp32:

```
rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
```

I haven't done anything yet because I'm only trying this out for the first time. I'm also not familiar in troubleshooting problems on the esp32 since this is the first time that I'm using this microcontroller. can someone help me. Thank you.